# How to setup flask with Parcel.js

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2, parcel

I have a flask application setup with Flask blueprint. Now I want to use parcel.js to bundle my projects. And also use postcss to remove unused css since I am using css framework in my project. But when I run the parcel command and give an entry, it gives error.

```
Server running at http://localhost:1234
```

×  C:\Users\afro\Desktop\streamify\afro\templates\index.html:1:104: Unexpected }

> 1 | background-image: url({{url_for('static',filename='music_posters/' + trending_musics.Music_cover_photo)}})
> |                                                                                                        ^

I think its because I am using Flask Jinja2 templating... I really don't know how to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your url in quotes.

```css
 background-image: url("{{url_for('static',filename='music_posters/' + trending_musics.Music_cover_photo)}}")
```